What's the difference between closing and exiting the terminal
I'm discovering the signals sent by the terminal when it exits. However, I found that there's a difference between typing exit to quit the terminal and directly clicking the x button.
Type Exit to quit the terminal
Terminal 1:
$ echo $$
31461

Termnal 2:
$ sudo strace -e signal -p 31461
strace: Process 31461 attached

Then I typed exit in Terminal 1. Terminal 2 output following message:
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x564317c26b00, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fa7c44fe090}, {sa_handler=0x564317c7d110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fa7c44fe090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x564317c265e0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7fa7c44fe090}, {sa_handler=0x564317c7d110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fa7c44fe090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {sa_handler=0x564317c26ed0, sa_mask=[HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fa7c44fe090}, {sa_handler=0x564317c7d110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fa7c44fe090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=0x564317c26ed0, sa_mask=[HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fa7c44fe090}, {sa_handler=0x564317c7d110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fa7c44fe090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {sa_handler=0x564317c265d0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7fa7c44fe090}, {sa_handler=0x564317c7c570, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7fa7c44fe090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x564317c26b00, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fa7c44fe090}, {sa_handler=0x564317c26b00, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fa7c44fe090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x564317c26b00, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fa7c44fe090}, {sa_handler=0x564317c26b00, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7fa7c44fe090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++

Click x button
Terminal 1:
$ echo $$
31519

Terminal 2:
$ sudo strace -e signal -p 31519
strace: Process 31519 attached

Then I closed the terminal by clicking the x button. Terminal 2 output following message:
--- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=3265, si_uid=1000} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b43b00, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b435e0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b43ed0, sa_mask=[HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b43ed0, sa_mask=[HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b435d0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b99570, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
kill(31519, SIGHUP)                     = 0
--- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=31519, si_uid=1000} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [HUP INT QUIT ALRM TERM TSTP TTIN TTOU], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b43b00, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b435e0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b43ed0, sa_mask=[HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
--- SIGCONT {si_signo=SIGCONT, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b43ed0, sa_mask=[HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
--- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b99570, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b435d0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b43b00, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b435e0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b43ed0, sa_mask=[HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b43ed0, sa_mask=[HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b435d0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b99570, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
kill(31519, SIGHUP)                     = 0
--- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=31519, si_uid=1000} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [HUP INT QUIT ALRM TERM TSTP TTIN TTOU], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b43b00, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b435e0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b43ed0, sa_mask=[HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b43ed0, sa_mask=[HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b99570, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b435d0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b43b00, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b435e0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b43ed0, sa_mask=[HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b43ed0, sa_mask=[HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b9a110, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b435d0, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b99570, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, {sa_handler=0x55c2f3b43ed0, sa_mask=[HUP INT ILL TRAP ABRT BUS FPE USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM XCPU XFSZ VTALRM SYS], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f26443d5090}, 8) = 0
kill(31519, SIGHUP)                     = 0
--- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=31519, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGHUP +++

pid 3265 displayed in the first line of message is about gnome-terminal-server
$ ps aux | grep 3265
kartone     3265  1.0  1.1 1013496 46336 ?       Ssl  11:23   0:13 /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server
kartone    31602  0.0  0.0  11984   720 pts/1    S+   11:45   0:00 grep --color=auto 3265

From main bash

The  shell  exits by default upon receipt of a SIGHUP.  Before exiting,
an interactive shell  resends  the  SIGHUP  to  all  jobs,  running  or
stopped.  Stopped jobs are sent SIGCONT to ensure that they receive the
SIGHUP.  To prevent the shell from sending the signal to  a  particular
job,  it  should be removed from the jobs table with the disown builtin
(see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below) or marked to not receive SIGHUP  us‐
ing disown -h.

The method of clicking x button seems to correspond to man bash because of SIGHUP, SIGCONT appears in the message.
I have searched online and found

Exiting the terminal vs Closing the terminal. The answer is ambiguous.
What's The Difference Between Exit and Closing A Terminal Graphically? says


closing the window instead of typing exit sends SIGHUP.

However, it means typing exit can't send SIGHUP, which is in conflict with man bash
The output messages of two methods of quiting the terminal are not completely same, so I have the questions:

Why the output messages are not same?
Are signals sent by the shell different between these two methods?
What's other differences between those two methods?

shopt
$ shopt -p huponexit
shopt -u huponexit

OS: VMWare's Ubuntu 20.04LTS

"However, it means typing exit can't send SIGHUP, which is in conflict with man bash" How did you arrive at this conclusion?

Alright, I'm not very sure about that. The article says typing exit can't send SIGHUP. And I have a try on running a while True python file in the background job. If I type exit, strace log outputs rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f5d02532090}, {sa_handler=0x611310, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f5d02532090}, 8) = 0  . If I close the terminal window, strace log outputs --- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=3416, si_uid=1000} --- +++ killed by SIGHUP +++

AFAIK a process can only send signals to its children - so the terminal can send SIGHUP to the shell running inside it, but a shell can't send SIGHUP to its parent terminal
